# Dropdown Lista angular

Tags: lista, angular, dropdownlist

Mi inquietud es la siguiente:
tengo un modal que cuenta con los siguientes campos quisiera hacer un "dropdownlist" o no conozco bien el nombre de esto pero me gustaria que cuando seleccione una opcion de seccion me cargue datos que solo corresponden a esta opcion seleccionada en seccion y asi sucesivamente[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: 1) El código que tienes en la imagen pegalo como texto, no como imagen. 2) De donde salen las `Divisiones` correspondientes a la `Seccion` seleccionada? y lo mismo con los grupos y clases.

Comment: las divisiones son de una plantilla de angular y el codigo lo tengo en array en un componente tengo entendido que es por medio de un ng*For pero no se como implementarlo

Comment: Lo siento @camilord50 no entiendo lo que estas diciendo.